# Рисование плавной линии

Tags: lua, алгоритм, cocos2d, c++

Отрисовываемая линия выходит угловатой если рисовать слишком быстро. Как осуществить сглаживание на лету, чтобы линия была более естественной?

красная отрисована с использование ccDrawLine, черная ccQuadBezier
[image]
<sub>(источник: [cs417423.vk.me](http://cs417423.vk.me/v417423988/612f/jYlfGB037ko.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для рисования линии сглаженной, есть специальный алгоритм - [Алгоритм Ву](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%92%D1%83). Там есть описание, как его реализовать.

Но похоже Вы делаете другое - простой графический редактор. И пользователь, проведя мышкой, должен получить <strike>ровную</strike>красивую кривую. Для этого, в процессе того, как пользователь рисует, нужно запоминать точки. Саму кривую рисовать в виде "ломанной кривой". Но когда пользователь отпускает мышку, берутся все сохраненные точки, с помощью кривых безье просчитываются красивые переходы и кривая отрисовывается. Если отрисовка достаточно быстрая, то просчитывать новую кривую можно на каждое движение мышки.

Да, при очень длинных кривых считать нужно будет долго, поэтому начало кривой кешируется, а просчитывается только конец.

Я рекомендую начать с простого запоминания точек от нажатия до отпускания, а по факту отпускания рисуйте красивую кривую.

Comment: Да сразу рисовать на лету красивую))

Comment: по идее у меня так и происходит - при появлении события onMove, то есть движение нажатой мыши/тача он рисует линию от последней до текущей точки. Но при быстром движении получаются угловатости. Как это решить?

Comment: если рисовать от последней до текущей, то шероховатости будут. Что бы избежать их, нужно помнить хотя бы 3-4 последние точки.

Comment: запоминать точки не проблема. Но как в таком случае отрисовывать Безье для этих четырех точек. у меня в качестве параметров для рисования линии безье используется четыре параметра - начало, контрольная точка, конец, количество сегментов. Контрольная точка на данный момент находится в середине между началом и концом.

Comment: вот посмотрел в [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162811(v=vs.85).aspx) - там просто нужно передать массив точек, оно все само нарисует. Никаких контрольных точек. Но эти линии будут проходить не объязательно по точкам. Если нужно что бы было строго по точкам, тогда нужно применять к примеру сплайны. Вот интересная [статья](http://learn.javascript.ru/bezier).

Comment: Мне необходимо либо написать собственную функцию рисования безье линий и внедрить её в cocos2d-x(хэшкод не имеет такого тэга, потому пришлось обойтись обычным кокосом), либо как-то обойтись стандартным безье. кроме того msdn рисует на неизвестное полотно, в то время как у меня используется CCRenderTexture. Тогда нужен ещё какой-то костыль.

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю альтернативу, вместо того, чтобы читать событие `onMouseMove` попробуйте определять положение мышки (в состоянии "рисую плавную линию" после нажатия левой кнопки вниз) в Таймере с очень маленьким "шагом", минимально в 1 мс. Исхожу из того, что событие `onMouseMove` не успевает "прочитать" каждое из положений мыши при быстром движении в силу особенностей сообщений.

Comment: вариант хорош, но как тогда передавать координаты?

Comment: в виндовсе это BOOL GetCursorPos(
    LPPOINT lpPoint   
   );, правда возвращает в системе координат экрана, но зная координаты клиентской области, можно легко исчислить в ней.

Comment: осуществлять доступ из-под lua к координатам экрана устройства - не лучший выбор я думаю.

Comment: а почему бы и нет?

Comment: в чем ее странность? Не декартовы что-ли? Чтоб не запутаться лучше перевод в систему координат сделать в отдельной функции (или что там у вас в луи?), а потом легко и просто ее вызывать, задавая в аргументов "родные" координаты луя

Comment: Странность в абсолютных и относительных координации различных структур кокоса. И таки метод с тиком не решает проблему - пользувателю все также придётся медленно водить для получения гладкой линии

Comment: Не получилось? Жалко. Было бы красивый "чистый" хак. Значит проблема фундаментальная в скорости считывания движений мыши, в слишком большой дискретности времени в событии, ведь на бумаге то мы можем нарисовать гладкую линию росчерком пера. (хотя теоретически дискретность в 1мс должна была хватить ИМХО) Тогда да, задачу надо решать алгоритмически, как указанно в ответах выше

Comment: а вообще может проблема в неудобстве рисования мышью. попробуйте пальцем по планшету, тоже так же получается?

Comment: собственно потому и понадобился алгоритм